# How to handle two inputs at the same time from Stdin Stream, one of them from the number pad in C?

Tags: c, windows, input, stdin

I want my program to read from the number pad and from the keyboard at the same time from the stdin stream.
I do not know if that's possible and this is why I'm asking.

My program is working properly, but if the first player is still pressing the arrow, the second one cannot move the paddle by pressing z/x at the same time unless the first stops pressing the arrow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <windows.h>

void first_player_arrow_press();
void second_player_Z_or_X_press();
void *second_player();

int arrow = 0, button_pressed = 0;
int z = 50;

int main()
{
    pthread_t my_thread;
    int x = 50;
    char buff[] = "################"; // the paddle
    char buff1[] = "                ";
    HANDLE hOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    while (1)
    {
        arrow = 0;
        button_pressed = 0;
        first_player_arrow_press();
        switch (arrow)
        {
        case 1:
            x = x;
            COORD clear1 = {x, 0};
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOutput, clear1);
            WriteConsoleA(hOutput, buff1, 15, NULL, NULL);
            x = x - 5;
            COORD coord = {x, 0};
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOutput, coord);
            WriteConsoleA(hOutput, buff, 15, NULL, NULL);
            break;
        case 2:
            x = x;
            COORD clear2 = {x, 0};
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOutput, clear2);
            WriteConsoleA(hOutput, buff1, 15, NULL, NULL);
            x = x + 5;
            COORD coord1 = {x, 0};
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOutput, coord1);
            WriteConsoleA(hOutput, buff, 15, NULL, NULL);
            break;
        }

        pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, second_player, NULL);
        pthread_join(my_thread, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}

void first_player_arrow_press()
{
    int ch = getch();
    if (ch == 0 || ch == 224)
    {
        switch (getch())
        {
        case 75: // left
            arrow = 1;
            break;

        case 77: // right
            arrow = 2;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void second_player_Z_or_X_press()
{
    int ch = getch();
    switch (getch())
    {
    case 122:
    case 90:     // left
        button_pressed = 1; // pressed Z , go left
        break;

    case 120:
    case 88:     // pressed X , go right
        button_pressed = 2;
        break;
    }
}

void *second_player()
{
    HANDLE hOutput1 = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    char buff[] = "################";
    char buff1[] = "                ";

    second_player_Z_or_X_press();
    switch (button_pressed)
    {
    case 1:
        z = z;
        COORD clears = {z, y};
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOutput1, clears);
        WriteConsoleA(hOutput1, buff1, 15, NULL, NULL);
        z = z - 5;
        COORD coords = {z, y};
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOutput1, coords);
        WriteConsoleA(hOutput1, buff, 15, NULL, NULL);
        break;

    case 2:
        z = z;
        COORD clears2 = {z, y};
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOutput1, clears2);
        WriteConsoleA(hOutput1, buff1, 15, NULL, NULL);
        z = z + 5;
        COORD coords1 = {z, y};
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOutput1, coords1);
        WriteConsoleA(hOutput1, buff, 15, NULL, NULL);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code — it is semi-unreadable because it is not yet indented.

Comment: Incidentally, note that your function declarations are not prototypes.  Prototypes for functions that take no arguments in C use `void first_player_arrow_press(void);` where the second `void` is crucial.  With empty parentheses, it's just a function that takes an indeterminate (but not variable — no ellipsis) number of arguments.

Comment: I didn't read your code but you could just determinate if the input is coming from the number pad if that's a digit.

Comment: Much better indentation now. Thanks.

Comment: It is going to depend on what the Windows keyboard driver does and how it interacts with the [`getch()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235446.aspx) — or, more likely, [`_getch()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx) — function.  If the `getch()` function won't report on the Z or X keys while the arrow key is still pressed, you're stuck until you work out how to finnagle the Windows system to give you the other key.  It is a problem solved by looking at the Windows API rather than the C code you show.  There are interesting comments in the referenced pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could also be a ghosting problem in the keyboard. If you look at gaming keyboards on amazon, some will have sets of anti-ghosting combination keys. These are keys that don't conflict with each other when used in combination.  [HAVIT HV-KB380L LED](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B019ICERYK) for instance has an anti-ghost on x/z and arrows.